# Bootstrap Scrollable List Group Scroll To Top

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using AngularJS, I have a list of messages that I display in a div that is marked as `pre-scrollabe` and inside is a bootsrtap `list-group` to display the individual messages:

```html
<div class="pre-scrollable">
    <ul class="list-group">

        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in MessageList">
            
            <!--Directive to Display Messages-->

        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

This yields the result that i want, a list of messages through which I can scroll. However I would like to know if there is a way that I can scroll to the top (or even the bottom for that matter) of the list using a JS function?

Comment: If you know the count of elements in the list, you can multiply that by the height of each element and set  Element.ScrollTop to that pixel (positive for top negative for bottom) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: On what element do I set the ScrollTop? The list-group Div?

Comment: I assume you need to put it on the list-group (but if that doesnt work you can try the pre-scrollable0